# Why adding status condition into left join block raised error?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

On new codeigniter 4.3.7 site with Mysql8 I have 3 joined tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`active` enum('A','I') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;




CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` enum('D','P','A','I') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D',
`sku` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `sku` (`sku`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;


CREATE TABLE `products_categories` (
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`product_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

I need to get all active categories with related products count and it works ok, until I added a condition
that products must be active too( ->where('p.status', 'A') ).

```
$data = $model->where('categories.active', 'A')
->select("categories.id as category_id, categories.name as category_name, categories.description as category_description, categories.created_at as category_created_at, COUNT(pc.id) as products_count")
->limit($num, $start)
->join('products_categories as pc', 'pc.category_id = categories.id', 'left')
->join('products as p', 'p.id = pc.product_id', 'left')
->where('p.status', 'A')
->groupBy('category_name')
->groupBy('category_description')
->groupBy('category_created_at')
->get();
```

That requests is rendered into sql :

```
SELECT `categories`.`id` as `category_id`, `categories`.`name` as `category_name`, `categories`.`description` as `category_description`,
`categories`.`created_at` as `category_created_at`, COUNT(pc.id) as products_count FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `products_categories` as `pc` ON `pc`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `products` as `p` ON `p`.`id` = `pc`.`product_id` WHERE `categories`.`active` = 'A' AND `p`.`status` = 'A'
GROUP BY `category_name`, `category_description`, `category_created_at` LIMIT 1, 10
```

and I got no data(must be 2 rows), but when I remove AND `p`.`status` = 'A'  I got 2 rows I need.

I tried to remade my sql manually and set AND `p`.`status` = 'A' UNDER left join block:

```
SELECT `categories`.`id` as `category_id`, `categories`.`name` as `category_name`, `categories`.`description` as `category_description`,
`categories`.`created_at` as `category_created_at`, COUNT(pc.id) as products_count FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `products_categories` as `pc` ON `pc`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `products` as `p` ON `p`.`id` = `pc`.`product_id` AND `p`.`status` = 'A' WHERE `categories`.`active` = 'A'
GROUP BY `category_name`, `category_description`, `category_created_at` LIMIT 1, 10
```

in this case the requested worked ok and I got 2 expected rows.

But when I tried to modify my request on codeigniter side :

```
$data = $model->where('categories.active', 'A')
->select("categories.id as category_id, categories.name as category_name, categories.description as category_description, categories.created_at as category_created_at, COUNT(pc.id) as products_count")
->limit($num, $start)
->join('products_categories as pc', 'pc.category_id = categories.id', 'left')
->join('products as p', " p.id = pc.product_id and p.status' = 'A' ", 'left')
->groupBy('category_name')
->groupBy('category_description')
->groupBy('category_created_at')
->get();
```

I got error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' = 'A' WHERE `categories`.`active` = 'A' GROUP BY
> `category_name`, `category_d' at line 4

What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might have a stray single quote after `p.status`

Comment: Yes, please write it as answer to accept it

Comment: If it was a typo, just close the question. Nobody else is going to google about join conditions in CakePHP and find such answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
->join('products as p', " p.id = pc.product_id and p.status' = 'A' ", 'left')
```

you have an extra single quote.

Instead, try

```
->join('products as p', " p.id = pc.product_id and p.status = 'A' ", 'left')
```